# How to know if my Calendar is shared to public in CalendarEntry

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

In the `CalendarEntry` class what is the field that correspond to the share property?

I want to know if the calendar I own is public or not and if the "Share only my free/busy information (Hide details)" checkbox is checked.

Could you provide me a example, to get set or insert the public property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read your setting via https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/userID/settings - there you can check the Visibility setting (public/private...).

For the full .NET API to Google Calendar see http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#SharingACalendar (this link directly goes to the part regarding sharing a calendar)...